# How postgresql gets time zone from my data?

Tags: postgresql, java, timestamp

I have a set of data containing latitude, longitude value, time and some other my application oriented values. In my application, a device is doing a job in a particular location during some time. So, it records the location and time. I want to import this record to postgresql database by a small java code. I made the time column as "timestamp with time zone" such as

```
String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE "+table_name +
              " (MachineId VARCHAR(20), " +
              " Timing TIMESTAMP(8) with time zone, " +
              " WorkMode INTEGER, " +
              " Latitude DOUBLE PRECISION, " +
              " Longitude DOUBLE PRECISION)"; 
stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
```

and inserted only the time values such as

```
time=2017:11:21:13:44:17:132;
SimpleDateFormat original = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss:SSS");
java.sql.Timestamp ts = null; 
try {
    java.util.Date timing = original.parse(time);
    ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(timing.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String sql = "INSERT INTO "+table_name +
             " (MachineId, "+
             " timing, " +
             " workmode, " +
             " latitude, " +
             " longitude)" +
             " VALUES" + 
             " ("+i+","+
             " '"+ts+"', " +
               workmode+", " +
               lat+", " +
               lon+");";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

But in postgres, it is showing "time+02" so, UTC+02 time zone is automatically detected which is correct time zone for my data. How does postgres detect this? Does this detect from lat and long values? Or what else?

Comment: Other clients would set the timezone when [connecting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) to the db. It has nothing to do with the coordinates you  have entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java will have a default TimeZone set which is applied to all `Date`s as they are created. 
So this line is the one that sets the timezone.

```
java.util.Date timing = original.parse(time);
```

You can override the one that is set in your JVM by using a line like:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: Ok, but how java detected correct time zone? Is it from my computer's time zone? As both are in same time zone; my data and my computer.

Comment: Yes, the default will be read from your machine's settings